# Keep getting the message: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to create a JWT Authorization in c# .net, but I keep getting the same error all the time : `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"`

This is the method which I configure the authentication and the authorization.

```
    public static void ApplyJwtServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<AuthenticationOptions>? authenticationOptions = null,
        Action<AuthorizationOptions>? authorizationOptions = null)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        if (authenticationOptions != null)
        {
            services
                .AddAuthentication(authenticationOptions)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => { options.TokenValidationParameters = ValidationParameters; });
        }
        else
        {
            services
                .AddAuthentication(auth =>
                {
                    auth.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options => { options.TokenValidationParameters = ValidationParameters; });
        }

        if (authorizationOptions != null)
        {
            services
                .AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddAuthorization();
        }
    }
```

I have `UseAuthorization()` and `UseAuthentication` and call the method above like this: `builder.Services.ApplyJwtServices();` in `Program.cs`.

This is how I generate the JWTToken:

```
    public static string Generate(Dictionary<string, object>? claims = null, DateTime? expiresAt = null, string? audience = null)
    {
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Expires = expiresAt ?? DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}
            },
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(ValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            Audience = audience ?? default
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.EncryptionKey))
        {
            tokenDescriptor.EncryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.EncryptionKey)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);
        }

        if (claims != null)
        {
            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                tokenDescriptor.Claims.Add(claim.Key, claim.Value);
            }
        }

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

and these are my appsettings:

```
    "SecretKey": "c2lnbnVtaWRqd3R0b2tlbnNlY3JldA==",
    "RequireAudience" : false,
    "ValidateIssuerSigningKey": false,
    "ValidateAudience": false,
    "ValidateIssuer": false,
    "RequireSignedTokens" : false
```

These are the validation parameters:

```
new()
        {
            RequireAudience = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.RequireAudience,
            IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.SecretKey)),
            TokenDecryptionKey = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.EncryptionKey)
                ? null
                : new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.EncryptionKey)),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
            ValidateAudience = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidateAudience,
            ValidateIssuer = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidateIssuer,
            ValidAudiences = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidAudiences ?? new List<string>(),
            ValidIssuers = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidIssuers ?? new List<string>(),
            ValidateActor = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidateActor,
            ValidateLifetime = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidateLifetime,
            ValidTypes = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.ValidTypes ?? new List<string>(),
            RequireExpirationTime = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.RequireExpirationTime,
            RequireSignedTokens = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.RequireSignedTokens,
            TryAllIssuerSigningKeys = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions.TryAllIssuerSigningKeys,
            IgnoreTrailingSlashWhenValidatingAudience = SignumIdGlobal.ApplicationSettings.JwtOptions
                .IgnoreTrailingSlashWhenValidatingAudience
        }
```

Everything is pretty much set to false(not to check) just to configure it and get it going but despite this I still get errors constantly.

This is a generated JWT: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0YmNjZWNmOC1mNTNhLTQ3ZjMtYWQ3Yi1kYTE2Zjc4OWJmYTUiLCJuYmYiOjE2Nzg2Mzc1MDIsImV4cCI6MTY3ODY0MTEwMiwiaWF0IjoxNjc4NjM3NTAyfQ.0rihJAzJ3Yc0yiRSWXLYViSN0qmYWvTiShWy8Qq2iZg`